# prefer const with constant constructor

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an error that shows this message "prefer const with constant constructor" when i deleting const on below class splashscreen theres not showing any error but throwing 
heres my code

```
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Image.network(
                "https://cdn.kibrispdr.org/data/white-background-hd-0.jpg"),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  "name",
                  height: 50,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 18,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Management",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                    ),
                  ],
                ) //Image Asset untuk logo splashscreen
              ],
            ),
          )
```

can someone help with this error really appreciate your help.

Comment: it's not error just info message

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an error, it's just an info message. This message comes from the `flutter_lints` package that tells you the recommended best practices.

You can learn more about `const` in Dart from [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const).

If you want to disable linting then go to the `analysis_options.yaml` file (present inside the root directory of your Flutter project) and comment out the line:

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml
```

But keep in mind this is not recommended.

Comment: hmm im really confusing i have 2 code one have those message and the other doesnt appear the message

Comment: @ImamRizkyGANTENG maybe in another part of the code, you have used a non-constant value (a variable). If you are talking about `const` constructor then a constructor is called constant when all the final attributes are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

To prefer const with constant constructors

Go to analaysis_options.yaml file in your Flutter project folder, then under rules title type
Prefer_const_constructors: false
Prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables: false
Then save it
Tip: Type it  not copy it